# Why could an XPath query only return the last match?

Tags: php, xpath

What are reasons why an XPath query could only return the last match? I am running a query on an HTML fragment which clearly has multiple `<a name="...">` tags, but the XPath query will only return one element, which happens to be the last element.

```
function extract($html) {
    // This test shows that the retrieved HTML fragment indeed contains multiple anchor tags
    echo "<textarea>".$html."</textarea>";

    // parse the data
    $dom = new DomDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTML($html); // we use @$dom to suppress some warnings
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

    // find the html code for the post
    $query = "//a[contains(@name, 'post')]"; 
    $rows = $xpath->query($query);

    // This will return 1
    echo "Elements found: " . count($rows);

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to probe `$rows->length`. The reason is that `$rows` is an instance of [`DOMNodeList`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php) (an object that holds a list of [`DOMNode`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php) instances). And since `DOMNodeList` doesn't implement the interface [`Countable`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.countable.php), it cannot be probed by [`count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) the way you'd expect. It simply returns `1`, because it is a single object, not the amount of `DOMNode`s it has aggregated.

And so, the result of your query does *not* return only the last match. It returns them all, and you can iterate through them with `foreach`, like so:

```
foreach( $rows as $row )
{
    // do something with $row (instance of DOMNode)
}
```

... or with a `for` loop, like so:

```
for( $i = 0, $len = $rows->length; $i < $len; $i++ )
{
    $row = $rows->item( $i );
    // do something with $row (instance of DOMNode)
}
```

... etc.